# jQuery Get touched element class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

**How do I get the touched element class name when using Iphones/Ipads?**

```
$(document).bind("touchstart", function (e) {
    var test1 = e.targetTouches[0].attr('class');
    var test2 = e.targetTouches[0].hasClass('menu-item')
    var test3 = $(e).attr('class');

    if (test1 != 'class-name')
        DoSomething();

    if (test2 != true)
        DoSomething();

    if (test3 != true)
        DoSomething();
});
```

**Noone of these three tests works.**

**This works on PC:**

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    var test = $(event.target).attr('class');

    if (test != 'class-name')
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

**Update:**

This closes the navbar when clicked on the screen.

```
    if ($(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("in"))
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
```

If I update the code to:

```
    var test = e.targetTouches[0].target.className;

    if ($(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("in"))
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
```

It no longer works. 
Is `var test = e.targetTouches[0].target.className;` really a valid expression?

Comment: Surely `var test = $(event.target).attr('class');` works in your first example as well?! (Or just `var test = event.target.className;`)

Comment: The interpreter doesn't even reach to the `if` statements. If you want to use jQuery methods you should at first create a jQuery object.

Comment: T.J - No, it doesn't work on iphones and ipads..
Vohuman - Can you show me in code what you mean? It works on all other devices except iphones and ipads, so it shouldn't be a problem..

Comment: @Reft: I find that very hard to believe. Can you create a Stack Snippet or jsFiddle or jsBin or similar demonstrating that?

Comment: Oh, do you mean $(document).ready(function (){}? Yeah I'm using that. Sorry lol

Comment: @Reft: No, he means that `e.targetTouches[0]` has no `attr` method.

Comment: That's a valid statement, what does `alert($(e.targetTouches[0].target).length)` show? Please learn debugging. You can use Safari.

Comment: @Reft: Sure enough, `e.target.className` works just fine for this in iOS Safari: http://jsbin.com/xuwuno But I've also shown you how to use `targetTouches` if that's important to you (for instance, for multi-touch stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use `targetTouches`, then you'll need to use the [`Touch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch) object's `target` property, which is a DOM element. If you want to use jQuery methods on it, you'll have to wrap it. Finally, to access anything that jQuery doesn't explicitly copy to the jQuery event object, you need to use the `originalEvent` property of the jQuery event object.

So for instance (using jQuery wrapper):

```
// Using `target` ---------------------------v
var test = $(e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].target).attr('class');
//         ^   ^-- using `originalEvent`            ^
//         +-- wrapping in jQuery obj --------------+
```

or just (direct to the reflected `className` property):

```
var test = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].target.className;
```

```js
$(document).on("touchstart", function(e) {
  if (!e.originalEvent.targetTouches) {
    console.log(e.type + ": No e.originalEvent.targetTouches");
  }
  else if (!e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0]) {
    console.log(e.type + ": No e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0]");
  }
  else if (!e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].target) {
    console.log(e.type + ": No e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].target");
  }
  else {
    console.log(e.type + ": e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].target.className: " + e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0].target.className);
  }

  // Note that as I said in a comment, `e.target.className` works just fine
  // for the main element
  console.log(e.type + ": e.target.className: " + e.target.className);
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 4em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="top">top div</div>
<div class="middle">middle div</div>
<div class="bottom">bottom div</div>
```